# trying to troubleshoot sound card issues

Tags: 12.04, sound

I'm trying to follow the article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

I'm on step five where it says to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-restricted-modules-`uname -r` linux-generic
```

But when I do, I'm getting the following error message:

devbox:/$ sudo apt-get install linux-restricted-modules-'uname-r' linux-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-restricted-modules-uname-r

am I supposed to substitute uname with something? sorry, i'm still pretty green with linux. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say that but the guide you followed is embarrassingly outdated (it also says so in the first line).

The package `linux-restricted-modules*` is deprecated since Ubuntu 8.04. You will not be able to install it in any newer release.

To answer your question on the meaning of `uname -r`: This is a replacement of your kernel release number as it can be printed by the following command in a terminal

```
uname -r
```

This is sometimes also used in a one-liner from tutorials to make sure you install a package version which depends on your installed kernel release.

Just to have said it: re-installing ALSA from the kernel will only rarely resolve common sound issues. To get help on these you may want to ask another question giving as much details on your issue, and what you already tried.